# Get current country from trip information

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a simple table (TRIP), which stores trip information like the following

```
trip_id traveler    country_from    country_to  departure_date  arrival_date
1        Test1       Germany         Italy       2016-01-01     2016-01-02
1        Test1       Italy           France      2016-04-01     2016-04-02
1        Test1       France          Italy       2016-08-28     2016-08-28
1        Test1       Italy           Germany     2016-08-30     2016-10-31 
2        Test2       France          USA         2016-01-28     2016-02-28 
2        Test2       USA             France      2016-08-30     2016-10-31
```

Actually this means that

```
Test1 travels: Germany -> Italy -> France -> Italy -> Germany 
Test2 travels: from France -> USA -> France
```

`departure_date` and `arrival_date` defines when traveler will leave `country_from`, and when he will be in `country_to`... actually it is `time spend in flight`

(I agree, this table is awful, and have lots of normalizing issues but I cant manage it, we have what we have)

I need to write a query, which will return traveler name, and the Country, in which traveler will be located (or if many countries the first country) for a given time period...

For example for time period 2016-03-01 - 2016-04-02 query should return

```
Test1 Italy
Test2 USA
```

Please advice optimal way to get that result, I have tried to join table itself with few variations, but always come to corner cases which are not covered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the beginning and end of the trip for each country in one row.  In SQL Server 2012+ you can use `lead()` for this purpose.  The rest of the query is just handling overlapping timeperiods:

```
select t.*
from (select t.country_to as country, t.arrival_date,
             lead(t.departure_date) over (partition by t.traveler order by arrival_date) as departure_date
      from trips t
      where t.traveler = @traveler
     ) t
where @date1 <= t.departure_date and
      @date2 >= t.arrival_date;
```

EDIT:

You can do the same thing in earlier versions using `outer apply`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.country_to as country, t.arrival_date,
             t2.departure_date
      from trips t outer apply
           (select top 1 t2.*
            from trips t2
            where t2.traveler = t.traveler and
                  t2.arrival_date > t.arrival_date
            order by t2.arrival_date
           ) t2
      where t.traveler = @traveler
     ) t
where @date1 <= t.departure_date and
      @date2 >= t.arrival_date;
```

Comment: Anyway this gives a great idea how to accomplish it, thanks... I use DENSE_RANK and inner join with -1, as you suggested in another answer :)